# Understanding the HTTP Headers

Tags: html, http-headers

I'm using a few application to check the goodness of my sites, and many ameliorations concerns missing http headers.

Examples : Content-Security-Policy, Charset etc ...

So I went to the [wikipedia page of HTTP Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) but I cannot find how to set properly the headers as the applications keeps telling me that I need to change those things.

So I'm asking : How to make good http headers for HTML5 ?
And knowing they don't recommend http-equiv, how can I set this ?

```
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=php/nojs.php">
    </noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Headers in HTML5 are found in the  element of your page. There are different headers for different stuff. Charset defines the character set they your page uses. The most common charset is utf-8. Content-Security-Policys define the way data is interpreted on the page. It is one of the steps to protect your site from XSS (Cross-site scripting) attacks. It So it really depends on what you are looking for, and what the 3rd applications are telling you to add.

But basically you add these "headers" in the `<head></head>` element of your page. So for example:

`<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>`

For more information on CS policys there is a nice guide [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)

I hope that helps, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I added meta charset="UTF-8" and yet the application PageSpeed Insight still tells me to specify a charset. I don't understand.

Comment: Might be a bug within the program itself. I'm not familiar with PageSpeed.